# Merge Two JSON Objects having the same Key

Tags: coldfusion, deserialization, lucee

I Have the JSON Like this

```
[{
      "Emails":"10@xyz.com"
   
},
   {
      "Emails":"20@xyz.com"
   
},
   {
      "Emails":"30@xyz.com"
   
},
   {
      "Emails":"40@xyz.com"
   
}]
```

output i am trying like this:

```
 [{
          "Emails":"10@xyz.com#chr10#20@xyz.com#chr10#30@xyz.com#chr10#40@xyz.com"
       
  }]
```

`chr(10)` for next line
and i am trying merge the values to the same key, so one key and multiple values

do i need to reverse to `deserialization` and rewrite it again in CF

Comment: One option to represent a single key with multiple values in JSON would be to use an array (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) instead of concatenating the values with line feeds in between. The result could look like this https://pastebin.com/tyt7xGgn

Comment: How much control do you have over the thing that created this JSON? I am thinking you don't want to change this. You want to change what created this.

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer keeping the emails in an array as a child of the "Emails" key.

1. Deserialize the original array.
2. Run [reduce operation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayreduce.html) on the array and create an array of emails.
3. Serialize the whole array again.

The following should work for lucee and newer versions of ACF.

```
<cfscript>
    // Presuming your initial JSON is being captured as a serialized string.
    origJSON = '[{
            "Emails":"10@xyz.com"
        },
        {
            "Emails":"20@xyz.com"
        },
        {
            "Emails":"30@xyz.com"
        },
        {
            "Emails":"40@xyz.com"
    }]';
    response = [{
        "Emails": deserializeJSON(origJSON).reduce(function(result=[], value){
            return result.append(value.emails);
        })
    }];
    
    writeoutput(serializeJSON(response));
</cfscript>
```

But if you still insist that you need to get a list of email with line break delimiter then you can add [`toList()`](https://cfdocs.org/arraytolist) (member function format of `arraytolist()`) to the end.

```
"Emails": deserializeJSON(origJSON).reduce(function(result=[], value){
    return result.append(value.emails);
}).toList(chr(10))
```

[DEMO](https://trycf.com/gist/7435adf00a2f2769992478f6aabe0cfa/lucee5?theme=monokai)

Comment: This is legit if they're using Lucee, this won't work in older version of ACF. Nice example of reduce. :)

Comment: Yes, the question was tagged as lucee. So I think OP is on lucee. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Good call, sorry somehow I missed that. oops :)

Comment: can i use it in queries of queries, i tried it but missing something

Comment: Can you update the question to what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes sure, the column has the json coming as above, I want to use query of queries and use the modified results of the column with the new way which you just showed using the reduce..

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is take the original JSON string and `deserialize()` it into a ColdFusion object which can then be easily converted into a  query object using `queryNew()`.  Then you can use `valueList()` to convert the column into a comma delimited string.  It's a compact solution only requiring 2 lines of code.

Here's the gist link https://trycf.com/gist/303d1abffd08a72379c796fc1a18302a/lucee5?theme=monokai

```
<cfscript>
// Presuming your initial JSON is being captured as a serialized string.
origJSON = '[{
        "Emails":"10@xyz.com"
    },
    {
        "Emails":"20@xyz.com"
    },
    {
        "Emails":"30@xyz.com"
    },
    {
        "Emails":"40@xyz.com"
}]';

// Code to convert serialized JSON array string into a new serialized JSON string containing a single key.
qry = queryNew("Emails", "varchar", deserializeJSON(origJSON));
newJSON = '[{#chr(13)##chr(10)#    "Emails" : "#valueList(qry.Emails)#"#chr(13)##chr(10)#}]';

// Output for display purposes
writeOutput('<pre>' & newJSON & '</pre>');

</cfscript>
```

**EDIT**

I noticed that you're looking for `chr(10)` as a delimiter for your email list. If this is really what you want, then it's just a simple minor modification by adding that as a second parameter to `valueList()` like so.

```
newJSON = '[{#chr(13)##chr(10)#    "Emails" : "#valueList(qry.Emails, chr(10))#"#chr(13)##chr(10)#}]';
```

Answer (score 0):

For that specific string, the ColdFusion replace function will achieve your objective.

```
<cfscript>
oriString = '[{
      "Emails":"10@xyz.com"
   
},
   {
      "Emails":"20@xyz.com"
   
},
   {
      "Emails":"30@xyz.com"
   
},
   {
      "Emails":"40@xyz.com"
   
}]';

newString = replace(oriString, chr(13), '', 'all');
newString = replace(newString, chr(10), '', 'all');
newString = replace(newString, ' ', '', 'all');
newString = replace(newString, '"},{"Emails":"', chr(10) , 'all');

</cfscript>
<hr>
<cfoutput>
    <pre>
        ori
        #oriString#
        new
        #newString#
    </pre>
    
</cfoutput>
```

You can test that code at https://trycf.com/gist/0fc39b7deeae8b5517bc7146054f88eb/lucee5?theme=monokai.

In real life, you might not have to replace the whitespace in the original string, depending on how it was generated.

Comment: this is a hacky solution, will not work if i have values from sql, it works for only one scenario and it is quite time consuming

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand you right, but what would be about:

```
<cfscript>
result={};
EmailList="";
oriString = '[{
      "Emails":"10@xyz.com"
   
},
   {
      "Emails":"20@xyz.com"
   
},
   {
      "Emails":"30@xyz.com"
   
},
   {
      "Emails":"40@xyz.com"
}]';
oriArray=deserializeJson(oriString).toArray();
for (i=1; i <= arrayLen(oriArray);i=i+1) {
    emailList=emailList.listAppend(oriArray[i]["Emails"],"#chr(10)#");
};
result["oriString"]=oristring;
result["emailList"]=emailList;
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#oristring#">
<hr>
<cfdump var="#emailList#">
<hr>
<cfdump var="#result#">
```

Answer (score -1):

They say, give a person fish, and you feed them for a day. Teach them to fish, and you feed them for a lifetime. Here then is an answer that fosters reuse:

```
<cfscript>
string function convertCompositeStructJSONToSingleStructJSON (string compositeStructJSON) {
    // Deserialize the JSON to an array of structs
    arrayFromJSON=deserializeJson(arguments.compositeStructJSON);
    
    // The key of any of the structs is the common key; take the first
    commonStructKey=listGetAt(structKeyList(arrayFromJSON[1]),1);
    
    // Compose new array based on array from JSON
    newArray=arrayNew(1);
    
    // Common key as first array element
    newArray[1]='[{"#commonStructKey#":"';
    
    // Fill out array with the respective struct values 
    arrayMap(arrayFromJSON, function(structItem){
                       arrayAppend(newArray, structFind(structItem, commonStructKey))               
                    });
     
    // Convert to list, adding chr(10) delimiter between the items               
    newListFromArray=arrayToList(newArray, chr(10)); 
                 
    // Append JSON ending as last list element               
    newListFromArray=newListFromArray & '"}]';    
    
    // Return a JSON string as result
    return newListFromArray     
}

// Reminder: in ColdFusion, [] signifies an array; JSON is a string
originalJSON='[{
      "Emails":"10@xyz.com"
   
},
   {
      "Emails":"20@xyz.com"
   
},
   {
      "Emails":"30@xyz.com"
   
},
   {
      "Emails":"40@xyz.com"
   
}]';

// Call function
newJSON = convertCompositeStructJSONToSingleStructJSON(originalJSON);

writeoutput(newJSON)
</cfscript>
```

Comment: I am curious to hear the comment of whoever marked down my answer.